# TypeError: X is undefined when attempting to alter item in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am building a JSON array out of elements from existing associative arrays, some of which I need to alter slightly before pushing them to my new array, but it doesn't work if I try to alter anything.

I can iterate through my master array `witness_work_array` and add an element from another array `work_array` to the third array `nodes_array` without any problem using this code:

```js
var nodes = [];    

var work_array = 
    [{"id":"1","name":"A Satyrical Ballad against Jack Hare","DIMEV":"45","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null},{"id":"2","name":"A knight that is hardy as a lion","DIMEV":"81","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null},{"id":"3","name":"A Complaint for my Lady of Gloucester and Holland","DIMEV":"159","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null}];
    
var witness_work_array =
    [{"id":"6","type":"witness_work","work_id":"2","witness_id":"2","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"7","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"3","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"8","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"4","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"9","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"5","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""}];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < witness_work_array.length; i++) {
    work = work_array.find(x => x.id === witness_work_array[i].work_id );

    nodes.push(work);
}

console.log(nodes);
```

But if I add the line `work.id = "otherwork" + work.id;` to the loop before pushing it to the new array:

```js
var nodes = [];    

var work_array = 
    [{"id":"1","name":"A Satyrical Ballad against Jack Hare","DIMEV":"45","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null},{"id":"2","name":"A knight that is hardy as a lion","DIMEV":"81","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null},{"id":"3","name":"A Complaint for my Lady of Gloucester and Holland","DIMEV":"159","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null}];
    
var witness_work_array =
    [{"id":"6","type":"witness_work","work_id":"2","witness_id":"2","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"7","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"3","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"8","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"4","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"9","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"5","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""}];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < witness_work_array.length; i++) {
    work = work_array.find(x => x.id === witness_work_array[i].work_id );
    
    work.id = "otherwork" + work.id;

    nodes.push(work);
}

console.log(nodes);
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: work is undefined
```

What I don't understand is why `work` is undefined if I attempt to alter something, but pushes through fine if I don't.  How do I need to modify the line in order to be able to change things?

Comment: That's not possible. `find()` either returns the object or `null`, it never returns `undefined`. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also, you can push `null` or `undefined` onto an array.  Setting a key on `null` or `undefined`, though, will error out.  Nothing wrong there.

Comment: There isn't much more to the project at this point than this code and the data. I've included a representative example of that as the full set of JSON for each would be annoying to deal with I suspect.

Comment: By asking for minimal example, they mean make your code a Stack Snippet (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or upload it to something like codesandbox. This reduces the level of effort needed to provide you with help.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you for the clarification. I didn't realize the snippets tool didn't require all the steps that the external example sites use.  I've added them above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying the objects in the `work_array` when you do `work.id = "otherwork" + work.id. So the next time you look for that ID, it can't be found and` find()`returns`undefined`.

This will happen whenever the same `work_id` is in multiple objects in `witness_work_array`.

You can make a copy of the `work` object before modifying it, so you don't affect the objects in the original array.

Also you should check the return value of `find()` to make sure it found something.

```js
var nodes = [];

var work_array = 
    [{"id":"1","name":"A Satyrical Ballad against Jack Hare","DIMEV":"45","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null},{"id":"2","name":"A knight that is hardy as a lion","DIMEV":"81","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null},{"id":"3","name":"A Complaint for my Lady of Gloucester and Holland","DIMEV":"159","type":"work","color":"midnightblue","size":null,"url_color":null,"link":null}];
    
var witness_work_array =
    [{"id":"6","type":"witness_work","work_id":"2","witness_id":"2","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"7","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"3","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"8","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"4","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""},{"id":"9","type":"witness_work","work_id":"3","witness_id":"5","status":"Planned","image_rights":"no","url":""}];


for (var i = 0; i < witness_work_array.length; i++) {
  var work = work_array.find(x => x.id === witness_work_array[i].work_id);
  if (work) {
    work = {...work, id: "otherwork" + work.id};
    nodes.push(work);
  } else {
    console.log("Can't find work_id " + witness_work_array[i].work_id);
  }
}

console.log(nodes);
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I thought that was what I was doing by adding the line

var work = work_array.find(x => x.id === witness_work_array[i].work_id);

My thought was that that declares a variable, which would then be populated with the results of work_array.find.  In turn, that would be pushed to nodes.

Why wouldn't that be a copy?

Comment: Because JavaScript doesn't copy objects, it just assigns references.